# Gives no error, but the data does not load

Tags: r, web-scraping

I don't understand what i am doing wrong:

```
 url <- "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=MRF&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0#"
    finance <- url%>%
    + html() %>%
    + html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="historicalData"]/table')%>%
    + html_table()
finance <- finance[[]]
```

I would like to extract the table from the url and get it into a dataframe for plotting.

Comment: If you want to ask another question, please open a new question. Changing the whole question is rude and not respecting those people who have helped you. Also, edit the old question will not make it appears in the timeline so few people will find your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no table with id 'historicalData' in the webpage if you have not click the 'get data' button.

```
url <- "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getHistoricalData.jsp?symbol=MRF&series=EQ&fromDate=undefined&toDate=undefined&datePeriod=1day"
finance <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//table')%>%
  html_table()
finance <- finance[[1]]
```

I think this code can help you. You may need to adjust the payload in the url to get the result you want.